# multiple selectbox value test using .each() jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

As it's clear from the following code that I am trying to loop through all select boxes but excluding some id's.

**Problem is**

Without using not selector it loops through all select boxes & does what it should. But when used with .not() selector, its skipping multiple type select boxes. Am i using some wrong syntax or missing something here.

```
$('.selectpicker:not("#Fresher, #Simple, #Advanced") :selected').each(function(i, sel){
    if (!$(sel).val()){
        $(this).closest("div:has(label)").find(".bootstrap-select").removeClass('formvalid').addClass('formerror'); 
        $(this).closest("div:has(label)").find("span.validation").removeClass('valid').addClass('error');
    }else{
        $(this).closest("div:has(label)").find(".bootstrap-select").removeClass('formerror').addClass('formvalid');
        $(this).closest("div:has(label)").find("span.validation").removeClass('error').addClass('valid');           
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<select id="Fresher" name="Fresher" multiple class='selectpicker show-menu-arrow' data-width='100%' data-size='10' title='Select Saved Search'>
 <option class="bs-title-option" value="">Select Saved Search</option>
 <option value="61">QUALITY</option>
 <option value="62">TEST</option>
 <option value="64">NEW SEARCH</option>
 <option value="66">NEW SEARCH</option>
</select>

<select id="f_Min_salary" name='Min_salary' class="selectpicker show-menu-arrow" data-width="100%" data-size="10" title='Select Min Salary'>
 <option class="bs-title-option" value="">Select Min Salary</option>
 <option value="101"><1 lakh</option>
 <option value="102">1 lakh</option>
 <option value="103">1.5 lakh</option>
 <option value="104">2 lakh</option>
</select>
```

**UPDATE**

apologies: i forgot to add attribute `MULTIPLE` in 1st select box. without multiple attribute it works fine as I mentioned above. for multiple select boxes it skips the validation.

**UPDATE-2**

Or is there any simpler way of matching current selectbox id with array of ids & if found then just ignore that particular selectbox from any rule.

Comment: When you are executing this JavaScript code?

Comment: I am executing this code once user click over submit button. It is wrapped inside a function `validateForm(obj, event)` which is gettting called onsubmit event of form.

Comment: I would be easy to debug things if you can create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Remove the space between your selector and `:selected` pseudo-selector. Spaces are really important in jQuery.</strike>

---

#### Edit:

Running this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7h6pz23d/1/), it looks like your jQuery selector works just fine. It's probably your classes toggling code that does not work as you expect.

---

#### Edit2:

Your selector works just fine with `multiple` selector option too: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7h6pz23d/2/)

---

#### Edit3:

I think I finally understand what the problem is - since you have multiple choices in your select element, you have to first select the `<select>` elements, and **then** check if there is at least one valid selection made.

```
$('.selectpicker:not("#Fresher, #Simple, #Advanced")').each(function (idx, selectEl) {
    var $selectEl = $(this);

    var isValid = false;
    $selectEl.find(":selected").each(function (idx2, optionEl) {
        var $optionEl = $(this);

        if ($optionEl.val()) {
            isValid = true;

            // This will break the loop on first valid element
            return false;
        }
    });

    console.log("isValid: ", isValid);
    // rest of your code
});
```

Of course, your validation logic might be different (eg. you want **all** selections to be valid), but I think you should be able to amend it on your own.

Comment: i have already tried this earlier. it stops selecting every selectbox available in loop :-(

Comment: Could you provide your HTML markup in the original post?

Comment: html added. what it is actually doing is, without using not selector it's validating both selectboxes for empty & highlighting with red border & error icon. but when used with not selector, it's doing nothing.

Comment: Please provide generated HTML code (with all the rows and values inserted), not the PHP generator code.

Comment: According to this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7h6pz23d/1/) I've created, you selector works just fine (open up the console, you will see "invalid" or "valid" once you click on "Run validation" button in the fiddle.

Comment: apologies, i forgot to add multiple attribute in 2nd select box. pls see update.

Comment: Please see ``Edit2`` - multi selector works just as fine as the single selector.

Comment: that didn't solved the issue. same problem persists. It's not creating red border outside empty select boxes (specially multiple type)

Comment: Sorry, but without the rest of the HTML, we cannot help you.

Comment: Please check `UPDATE 2` if you can help in some way

Comment: no, its not because when i use `alert($(sel).closest('.selectpicker').attr('id'));` before `if (!$(sel).val())` then it doesn't shows multiple type selectbox ids. if u see your fiddle with multiple type select box then also it shows similar action (provide add multiple attribute in 1st select box)

Comment: [Another JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7h6pz23d/5/). When I select ``1 lakh`` and ``1.5 lakh`` it shows ``f_Min_salary`` twice in the console. So it does work...

Comment: now i believe, i can help in understanding the issue correctly. without selecting any option if you click submit button, it will not show `invalid` which it should. Thats my problem. after selcting options it works fine. But without any selection if user clicks on submit button then it hightlights only non-multiple select boxes only.

Answer (score 0):

Do your checkboxes have the class .selectpicker or are they children of .selectpicker?
Because you are selecting every :select following after .selectpicker.

Comment: these are not checkboxes. Actually these are select boxes & every selectbox have class `.selectpicker`

Comment: You should take a closer look to the jQuery documentation for :selected
**The :selected selector works for <option> elements. It does not work for checkboxes or radio inputs; use :checked for them.**
When you dont have a multi select, each select will only have one :selected option.

Answer (score 0):

$('.selectpicker:not("#Fresher, #Simple, #Advanced"):selected').each(function(i, sel){

});

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

posted suggestions/answers didn't worked as per question requirement hence i had to find out some other method using `UPDATE-2` alertnative, which worked [**bingo**] as desired. Hope this can help someone else too !!

**ID's of element should be excluded**

```
var codes = ["Fresher", "Simple", "Advanced"];
```

**modified jquery**

```
$('.selectpicker').each(function(i, sel){           
    var idname = $(sel).closest('.selectpicker').attr('id');
    if($.inArray(idname, codes) == -1)
    {
        if (!$(idname).val()){
            $(this).closest("div:has(label)").find(".bootstrap-select").removeClass('formvalid').addClass('formerror'); 
            $(this).closest("div:has(label)").find("span.validation").removeClass('valid').addClass('error');
        }else{
            $(this).closest("div:has(label)").find(".bootstrap-select").removeClass('formerror').addClass('formvalid');
            $(this).closest("div:has(label)").find("span.validation").removeClass('error').addClass('valid');           
        }
    }
});
```

Using above code now we have more flexibility across multiple pages to ignore certain id's.

Thanks all for your effort in helping. specially **@mdziekon**